# When does a Bitcoin Core node first start getting inbound peers?

Tags: synchronization, peers, connection

It is my understanding that a fresh node will only make outbound connections during IBD and not advertise its own IP address, yet. Since other nodes will only advertise IP addresses that they learn about from peer gossip, I would expect that a node during IBD should generally not have incoming connections.

When does a node start getting incoming connections? Would a node in IBD permit to make an inbound connection?